# Can one purchase a Cessna 182JT-A although it has not yet been certified?

Tags: general-aviation, aircraft-certification, cessna-182

To the best of my knowledge, Cessna's 182JT-A has not yet been certified. At least I couldn't find on Google any indication that it has. Lots of items that certification is "imminent" but no real facts.

Yet, I see them for sale and YouTube has videos of them flying. Am I correct in believing that it is possible to buy one and then operate it as an experimental aircraft?

Comment: The FAA's Type Certificate for the 182 was last updated on Dec. 20, 2011, leading me to believe it is not certificated in the USA at this time. http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgMakeModel.nsf/0/94AA23D4EBDA7EB78625796D006AAEFD?OpenDocument

Comment: I poked around and saw that they sold one in New Zealand (which doesn't need FAA certification).  Everything else I've seen where they are for sale, it looks like they are selling *production slots*, even brokers are selling a date you get the plane, not necessarily an airplane from their own inventory.  If you buy one from Cessna in the US, it looks like they give you a date for delivery, but not like there is a show room full of airplanes and you fly one off the lot. I can't find proof, but I don't believe the litigation-averse Cessna would sell you one under the experimental class.

Comment: I have a Cessna 182 and always stop in the Cessna booth at Oshkosh every year.  The 182JT as of the end of July was still classified as experimental but they were expecting a certification within the next few months.  My guess is that it should be any day.  You can, however, buy one now - you just won't get it until it's officially released (prebuy).  They do have to have models flying to demonstrate safety, but they are Cessna owned airplanes.

Comment: @ScottJohnson I corresponded with via email with the Cessna dealership in Hillsboro, OR a couple of weeks ago. They had no idea when it was going to be certified, but I got the impression that they weren't expecting it to happen anytime soon. Interestingly, while Cessna still shows the JT-A on the their website as one of their products, they have taken it off the range map accessible at http://cessna.txtav.com/aircraft-range-tool.

Answer (score 1):

They did have an engine out failure about a year ago which set everything back a bit.  They've had it at Osh a couple of years now.  Two years ago they were saying around the end of '14 beginning of '15.  Last summer, they were saying months.  If you're really curious, I would talk to the manufacturer in Kansas.  Dealers really aren't part of the FAA approval process...

I wouldn't read too much into the range calculator.  I would imagine that they would be adjusting numbers numerous times before release as they get more data.

Comment: I hope that is the case. However, the JT-A was in the range calculator a couple of months ago.